# Builder pattern not working

Tags: java, design-patterns, libgdx, builder

So I am currently working on a game in Java with the help of LibGDX. Recently I bumped into a problem, when tryin to make a Builder class for another class which will have a lot of parameters, so I guessed it needs a Builder class. Being the confident java programmer I am, I started it and I found a problem which I can't correct. I have already looked it up on the internet and found some examples, but everything seems OK for me. Maybe you can help. The code needed:

```
public class SpecialTile implements MyAnimation {

    /**
     * Class builder for SpecialTile
     * @author Zsemberi Daniel
     *
     */
    public static class SpecialTileBuilder {
        /*
         * Drawables
         */
        private Sprite image;
        private Animation anim;

        //position
        private Point position;

        /**
         * Sprite path constructor
         */
        public SpecialTileBuilder(String imagePath) {
            this.image = new Sprite((Texture) Load.manager.get(imagePath));
        }

        /**
         * Image constructor
         */
        public SpecialTileBuilder(Sprite image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        /**
         * Animation constructor
         */
        public SpecialTileBuilder(Animation anim) {
            this.anim = anim;
        }

        //Set position
        public SpecialTileBuilder setPosition(Point position) {
            this.position = position;
            return this;
        }


        public SpecialTile createSpecialTile() {
            return new SpecialTile(this);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Drawables
     */
    private Sprite image;
    private Animation anim;

    private float stateTime = 0f;

    //position
    private Point position;

    protected SpecialTile(SpecialTileBuilder builder) {
        image = builder.image;
        anim = builder.anim;
        position = builder.position;
    }

    /**
     * Hits the player
     */
    public boolean isHit(Sprite sprite) {
        if(anim == null)
            return image.getBoundingRectangle().contains(sprite.getBoundingRectangle());
        else
            return new Sprite(getCurrentFrame()).getBoundingRectangle().contains(sprite.getBoundingRectangle());
    }

    /**
     * If it is triggered it does something
     */
    public void doTheHarlemShake(Sprite sprite) {

    }

    public Sprite getSprite() { return image; }
    public Animation getAnimation() { return anim; }

    public float getX() { return position.x; }
    public float getY() { return position.y; }

    /*
     * Animation stuff
     */

    @Override
    public TextureRegion getCurrentFrame() {
        return anim.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateAnimation(float delta) {
        stateTime += delta;
    }

}
```

So up there you can see the whole class (I thought you may need it) where I wrote the Buidler. And here comes how I would use it if it worked.

```
SpecialTile.SpecialTileBuilder("test.png")
                .setPosition(new Point(2, 2))
                .createSpecialTile();
```

So it says in eclipse that I have got this problem:

> The method SpecialTileBuilder(String) is undefined for the type
>   SpecialTile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just forgot the `new`. You should be creating a new `SpecialTile.SpecialTileBuilder` instance, but you are trying to call the `SpecialTile.SpecialTileBuilder(...)` method.

Comment: Oh my God. I feel so stupid now. I have been stuck on this for half an hour now. I will accept your answer as soon as possible. Thanks :)

Comment: @DanielZsemberi you’re welcome. I know from personal experience that sometimes there is a trivial error that you just don’t see. :)

Comment: Yes exactly, and that's why I personally like working in a group. Again thanks.